# Angular router - way to identify, does the router perform initial navigation or it comes from app

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Hello Stack community.

As in question title, I'm wondering is there a way to identify, does a view in Angular is rendered as a subsequent Angular Router navigation request (i.e. internal navigation request)

or

does a view is rendered due to user typing exact URL in his browser bar and view comes up as  first view of the app?

Example would be user performing some sort of ordering on page `my.page.com/order`

and then clicking on this page on button that will invoke `router.navigate(['next'])`

vs

entering directly `my.page.com/order/next` to his URL.

Do we have some trusted and production-grade ready solution for this?

Comment: When you type the URL, you will get `index.html` which starts the Angular application, and then the app decides what to render based on the URL. Therefore it's the same whether you hit the URL directly or navigate via `Router`. What you can do is pass extra data upon navigation and then check for it. For example: `router.navigate(['next'], {state: {innerNavigation: true}})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to router events and then filter out all the navigation end events, then pairwise will emit the last value and the current value, then you store it in variables of a component, or on a service and then solve your issue!

This is from a previous answer, but the gist is on load, you will be getting previousPath as null, while when navigation happens, previous path will contain a value!

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((x) => x instanceof NavigationEnd), // filter out only the navigation end event
        startWith(null), // set an initial value
        map((x) => x && x.url), // get only the necessary value
        pairwise() // emit both the previous and current value
      )
      .subscribe((event) => {
        console.log('navigation succeeded', event[0], event[1]);
        this.previousPath = event[0];
        this.currentPath = event[1];
      });
  }
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-event-ecc5zc)

Comment: genius! I'v been handling this in router events as well but in way more clumsy way! Many thanks <3